# How to center the icons using css

Tags: html, css

I have a mini project here. When I try to `text-align: center;` in body, the icons don't follow. If I remove the `left: 0;` in .content-label i in css, it stays on the right and I have no clue how to put it on the left side.

For more info, please check my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/Foxseiz/zse8tuL9/2/

Comment: Put the *<i></i>* element before the *input* instead of behind it

Comment: If I do that, the icons wont turn blue when the input is active. @Gerard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go.

> Try not to use position absolute as first priority as its the last option to style and element :)

```css
/* CSS files add styling rules to your content */
body {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif !important;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 180px;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-color: dodgerBlue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;
}

.content-label input[type="text"] {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.content-label {
  position: relative;
}

.content-label i {
  left: 0;
  top: 8px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.content-label input[type="text"]:focus + i {
  color: dodgerBlue;
}

.content-label.inputIconBg i {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  line-height: inherit !important;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-label.inputIconBg input[type="text"]:focus + i {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: dodgerBlue;
}
.content-label {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ed2e310181.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="full-content">
      
      <div id="content">
        
        <form autocomplete="off">
          <div class="content-label inputIconBg">
            <input type="text" id="cost" placeholder="Cost"/>
            <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cost" data-placement="left"></i>
          </div>
        
          <div class="content-label inputIconBg">
            <input type="text" id="margin" value="1.4" placeholder="Margin"/>
            <i class="fas fa-coins" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Margin" data-placement="left"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="content-label inputIconBg">
            <input type="text" id="labor" value="35" placeholder="Labor"/>
            <i class="fas fa-hammer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Labor" data-placement="left"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="content-label inputIconBg">
            <input type="text" id="shipping" value="15" placeholder="Shipping"/>
            <i class="fas fa-truck" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Shipping" data-placement="left"></i>
          </div>
        </form>
        
        <button id="calc" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
      </div>
      
      <p id="result"></p>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Use

```
.content-label.inputIconBg i {
    margin-right: -42px;
 }
```

to align icon inside input

Comment: Good to hear that @Foxseiz , Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flexbox.
You can set your `content-label` as `flex` element and center with `justify-content` property.
N.B. i used `order` property because you set the i tag after the input, so i change the order.

```css
/* CSS files add styling rules to your content */
body {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif !important;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 180px;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  border-color: dodgerBlue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;
}

.content-label input[type="text"] {
  padding-left: 50px;
  order:2;
  
}

.content-label {
  position: relative;
  display:flex; /* add this */
  justify-content:center; /* add this */
}

.content-label i {
  /*position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 8px;*/ /* comment this */
  margin: 9px 0 8px 8px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
  order:1;
}

.content-label input[type="text"]:focus + i {
  color: dodgerBlue;
}

.content-label.inputIconBg i {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  line-height: inherit !important;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-label.inputIconBg input[type="text"]:focus + i {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: dodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ed2e310181.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="full-content">
      
      <div id="content">
        
        <form autocomplete="off">
          <div class="content-label inputIconBg">
            <input type="text" id="cost" placeholder="Cost"/>
            <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Cost" data-placement="left"></i>
          </div>
        
          <div class="content-label inputIconBg">
            <input type="text" id="margin" value="1.4" placeholder="Margin"/>
            <i class="fas fa-coins" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Margin" data-placement="left"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="content-label inputIconBg">
            <input type="text" id="labor" value="35" placeholder="Labor"/>
            <i class="fas fa-hammer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Labor" data-placement="left"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="content-label inputIconBg">
            <input type="text" id="shipping" value="15" placeholder="Shipping"/>
            <i class="fas fa-truck" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Shipping" data-placement="left"></i>
          </div>
        </form>
        
        <button id="calc" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
      </div>
      
      <p id="result"></p>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```